# What is wrong with this case statement ? Getting Missing Keyword error

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am not sure why i am getting Missing keyword error for the below case statement.

```
WHERE tb.BOOKED_DATE = TO_DATE($P{pFromDate}, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
AND (case when $P{pTxnStatusId} = '11' then pg.RESPONSE_CODE is Not Null else pg.RESPONSE_CODE = $P{pTxnStatusId} end)
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is SELECT statement?

Comment: why do you need select statement ?

Comment: It's meant to be of the form `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <value1> else <value2> END` but you don't seem to have any values - where your first value should be, you've got another condition, and where your second value should be you've got an expression. I think you should clarify what you're trying to do!

Comment: What is the logic that you're trying to put in the case statement? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: pTxnStatusId will have 2 values 0 and 11. If 11 need to display all the records else only the values with response code 0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a case statement is what you want here, you seem to be trying to apply logic to your where statement. Try this instead, converting to ANDs and ORs:

```
WHERE tb.BOOKED_DATE = TO_DATE($P{pFromDate}, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
AND (($P{pTxnStatusId} = '11') OR ($P{pTxnStatusId} = '0' AND pg.RESPONSE_CODE = 0))
```

Comment: No this won't work for me.. I need logic to be implemented here, pTxnStatusId will have 2 values 0 and 11. If 11 need to display all the records else only the values with response code 0

Comment: @SrikanthSridhar I copied the logic from the question. I've edited - have a look now. I assumed you still wanted to check the dates.

Comment: Sorry, here we are checking only the pTxnStatusId value. I need to assign the pTxnStatusId value to pg.Response_code only if it is zero else i need to retreive all the records except where pg.Response_code is null. That is the reason why iam trying with case statement

Comment: If you want to assign, why are you doing it in the where clause? Run two separate statements to assign the value, with different where clauses as appropriate.